# Django Annotation, Django doing a double outer left join

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I am in a bit of a problem.

I have a model called Customer
I also have two other models called Invoice and Payment
Now, Invoice is FK to Customer and Payment is FK to Invoice

I want a query where I find out how much of balance is due from customer.

My Invoice model has, among others the following fields:

```
invoice_id = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=12)
total=models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
grand_discount=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='salesInvoice_sales_master_customer')
```

My payment model is as follows:

```
invoice_no=models.ForeignKey(salesInvoice, related_name='salesPayment_sales_sales_salesInvoice')
amount_paid=models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
collected_on=models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

Now, I am calling the on the annotate on Customer object  as follows:

```
customers = Customer.objects.for_tenant(request.user.tenant).annotate(total=
    Sum('salesInvoice_sales_master_customer__total')\
    -Sum('salesInvoice_sales_master_customer__grand_discount')\
    -Sum('salesInvoice_sales_master_customer__salesPayment_sales_sales_salesInvoice__amount_paid'))
```

Everything is working file till the last line (I checked by removing the last SUM on sales payment. i.e. the payment model). As this query is put, Django does a "double" LEFT OUTER JOIN on invoice model, as a result total and grand_discount is getting doubled. For example is total is 1000, grand_discount is 100, amount_paid is 500, the query shows total is 2000, grand_discount as 200 and amount_paid as 500

Is there any way this could be solved, other than RAW SQL (my DB is postgresql)?